# NativeModules.MyNativeModule is undefined in iOS in react native 0.61.2

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I have a react native library I am writing. It stays in local as of now so I install it with

`yarn add ../MyNativeModule`

Then in my code, I import it as

`const MyNativeModule = NativeModules.MyNativeModule;`. This works fine on android, but on iOS, it does not work. I get `MyNativeModule` as `undefined`.

My native module:

```
android
    ...
ios
    MyNativeModule.h
    MyNativeModule.m
    MyNativeModule.xcodeproj
index.js
MyNativeModule.podspec
```

`MyNativeModule.h`

```
#import <React/MyNativeModule.h>

@interface MyNativeModule : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule>

@end
```

`MyNativeModule.m`

```
#import "MyNativeModule.h"

@implementation MyNativeModule

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()

@end
```

My podspec:

```
require 'json'

package = JSON.parse(File.read(File.join(__dir__, 'package.json')))

Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name         = "MyNativeModule"
  s.version      = package['version']
  s.summary      = package['description']
  s.license      = package['license']

  s.authors      = package['author']
  s.homepage     = package['repository']['url']
  s.platform     = :ios, "9.0"
  s.ios.deployment_target = '9.0'

  s.source       = { :git => "" }
  s.source_files  = "ios/**/*.{h,m}"

  s.dependency 'React'
end
```

I have tried:

```
1. Removed and re-installed everything.
2. Cleared caches of pods and metro.
3. I tried changing the s.source on my podspec to the local repo.
4. I tried changing the s.source_files to "ios/*.{h,m}"
```

I have been trying this whole day now and nothing has worked yet. Some help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, looks like I just had to implement a function in `MyNativeModule.m`. So it doesn't work without at least one function.

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(addEvent:(NSString *)name location:(NSString *)location)
{
  RCTLogInfo(@"Pretending to create an event %@ at %@", name, location);
}

@end
```